# Implement Level Security in NHibernate in SQL Server 2016

Tags: c#, nhibernate, sql-server-2016, row-level-security

I am trying to implement row-level security in SQL Server using Nhibernate. I wanted to use this approach: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-entity-framework-row-level-security/.

I created an interceptor in nhibernate:

```
public class TenantInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor
{
    private readonly ITenantResolver _tenantResolver;

    public TenantInterceptor(ITenantResolver tenantResolver)
    {
        _tenantResolver = tenantResolver;
    }

    public override void SetSession(ISession session)
    {
        string tenant = "sampleTenant";

        if (_tenantResolver.Current != null)
            tenant = _tenantResolver.Current.Id;

        string queryFormat = @"Exec sp_set_session_context @key=N'@Tenant', @value='{0}'";
        string query = string.Format(queryFormat, tenant);

        session.CreateSQLQuery(query)
            .ExecuteUpdate();

        base.SetSession(session);
    }
}
```

I attached it to the session in this way:

```
if (!CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(GetSessionFactory()))
{
    _session = GetSessionFactory().OpenSession(new TenantInterceptor(_tenantResolver));
    CurrentSessionContext.Bind(_session);
}
else
{
    _session = GetSessionFactory().OpenSession(new TenantInterceptor(_tenantResolver));
}
```

And also I have a following code in SQL Server:

```
CREATE SCHEMA [Security]
go

CREATE FUNCTION [Security].tenantAccessPredicate(@Tenant nvarchar(255))
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    RETURN 
        SELECT 1 AS accessResult
        WHERE @Tenant = CAST(SESSION_CONTEXT(N'@Tenant') AS nvarchar(255)) OR @Tenant = ''
```

So I thought that I did everything right. But when I run query from my application I never receive any rows. When I copy the exact same SQL code and run it from SQL Server Management Studio, everything works and I get expected rows.

Can anyone help me? I have no idea what I have done wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is quite old, but maybe my answer will help someone.
It worked for me when I used the ADO.NET's API instead of NHibernate's:

```
public override void SetSession(ISession session)
{
    using (var cmd = session.Connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        var param1 = cmd.CreateParameter();
        param1.ParameterName = "@key";
        param1.Value = "TenantId";

        var param2 = cmd.CreateParameter();
        param2.ParameterName = "@value";
        param2.Value = _tenantResolver.Current.Id;

        cmd.CommandText = "sp_set_session_context";
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    base.SetSession(session);
}
```